# DB writes are executed lazily with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-streaming

HBase puts are not executed while Spark Streaming is running, only when I'm shutting down Spark - it tries to perform all puts altogether

```
val inputRdd = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc, "server", 44444)
  inputRdd.foreachRDD({ rdd =>
    rdd.foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords => {
      val hbaseClient = new HBaseClient(zookeeper)
      partitionOfRecords.foreach({ event =>
         hbaseClient.put(parse(event))
         hbaseClient.flush()
```

Comment: DId you try to create HBaseClient inside forechPartition ?

Comment: This is what it looks like @axlpado-AgileLab

Comment: @axlpado-AgileLab I've updated code - it was already inside

Comment: partitionOfRecords.foreach( event => {
         hbaseClient.put(parse(event))
         hbaseClient.flush()})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok - I've found my answer - apparently my code was correct, the problem was I didn't leave enough threads for processing the data

from
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html
"""
If you are using a input DStream based on a receiver (e.g. sockets, Kafka, Flume, etc.), then the single thread will be used to run the receiver, leaving no thread for processing the received data. Hence, when running locally, always use “local[n]” as the master URL, where n > number of receivers to run (see Spark Properties for information on how to set the master).
"""

using local[*] fixed the issue